# Блокировка перехода на страницу через headers

Tags: php

Здравствуйте
Делаю сайт по скачиванию разных программ, ссылки на скачивание генерируются временные (прим. http://site.ru/downloads/bdb33c054e7f120b74f7867efcfa0633).

При клике по этой ссылки скрипт отдает файл через заголовки и непосредственно переход по ссылке не осуществляется (это если файл существует).

А как сделать так чтобы при отсутствии файла(того что отдается через headers) переход по ссылке тож не осуществялся ?

Спасибо заранее!

Код на странице. $file - адрес файла.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {

    // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
    // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }

    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . rand(0,999).'.'.end(explode(".", basename($file))) );
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
```

Comment: код какой-нить приведите, а-то непонятно что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: А что мешает проверять имеется ли файл на предыдущей странице и не генерировать ссылку? Ну если только не защита от прямых ссылок конечно. Но это всего лишь доработка. Ну а что касается "не перехода", то здесь никак, потому что HTTP по-любому делает GET URL по клику, и что-то все равно надо отдавать назад клиенту - либо контент (страницу) либо направлять на стандартный 404.

Comment: Так устроит?  

    <a href="адрес_на_файл" target="x">test</a><iframe name="x" style="display:none"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по клику ни чего не произойдёт если вернуть 404

```
if (file_exists($file)) {

    // если ob_start() вызван более одного раза
    while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . rand(0,999).'.'.end(explode(".", basename($file))) );
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
}else{
    // отдаём 404, что важно для поисковиков
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
}
```

Comment: Хром переходит по ссылке и выводит:  

    Ошибка. Ссылка не работает.
    Попробуйте:
    Искать в Google:

Comment: @ReinRaus, вы правы. Думаю наши ваш совет следует скомбинировать с моим ответом

Comment: Реакция хрома - это его личное дело :) Важно что отдаётся по ссылке, проверяется просто: wget -S "http://ссылка". Если там честный 404 без выкрутасов, то всё в порядке, если что-то другое - надо разбираться.

Ну или не факт, что вообще надо отдавать 404, кто мешает отдать 200 и страницу с объяснениями? Тем более что поисковикам эти ссылки совершенно не нужны.

Comment: @klopp, если там чистый 404, то браузер должен показать страницу 404. Хром это первый попавшийся браузер на котором решение не сработало, остальные не стал тестировать. Скоро и в опере будет так же работать, когда она на вебкит перейдет

Comment: @klopp, 200 категорически нет. По личному опыту, на сайте в поисковиках выходит очень много мертвых ссылок, что не очень радует пользователей. С HTTP нужно работать корректно

Comment: @Gedweb, из условия следует, что эти ссылки генерятся одноразово. Их вообще имеет смысл запрещать индексировать.

@ReinRaus, какую 404? Если сервер не настроен на корректную отдачу 404, то тут уж кто во что горазд, претензии никак не к честному HTTP.